# Material won’t render, but does show up in the 3D viewport with “Material shading” (project file included)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

Today I came across a strange problem: a material just won’t render, model is just white! Object is showing up textured in the 3D viewport with “Material shading”
[image]
, but it’s completely white in the render 
[image]

Render engine is Cycles. Nodes are used.
Object has a single UV, so UV is not the problem.

[image]

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include: what rendering engine are you using? (Cycles, Blender Internal or other), how have you set up the material? does it use nodes? If you can, uploading a file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com will help us help you more effectively!

Comment: @Nicola Sap Done!:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your node setup you are connecting **color** outputs and **BSDF** inputs. Cycles is not meant to work like that (hence there is no rendered material). The viewport will still show something, because it is an approximation which evaluates nodes differently.

- Connect color outputs with color inputs.
- Connect BSDF outputs with BDSF inputs.

You can use either method to create your setup. Color outputs can be mixed with a **MixRGB** node and BSDF outputs can be mixed with the **Mix Shader** node.

[image: node setup]